# Android Listview's section headers

Tags: android, android-listview, sectionheader

How to 'Stack the section headers' on top of the list view after scrolling it? I mean, to stack section headers like in Free cell game. Attached is the image for reference. This is how i want to stack all headers on top.

[image: Free cell example]

Thanks in advance.